# Set all numbers to have General DisplayFormat using win32com and Excel and Python

Tags: excel, precision, numeric, pywin32, win32com

We have an application that needs to process Excel spreadsheets. Some of them come in with crazy number formatting, so that numbers like 1.23456789 are displayed as 1.23. We need to automatically remove this formatting, and only this formatting. It seems like the right way to do it is to write a program using the python win32com API, have Excel open a spreadsheet, and then change the formatting on cells with numbers to be General.

What's the easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple code snippet that loops over all cells in an excel workbook and conditionally updates each cell's number formatting. It uses [`xlwings`](https://docs.xlwings.org), which is in essence a powerful and user-friendly wrapper around the python win32com API.

```python
import xlwings as xw

book = xw.Book('example.xlsx')
for sheet in book.sheets:
    for cell in sheet.used_range:
        if cell.number_format == '0.00':
            cell.number_format = 'General'
```